# TkinterのcanvasでNameErrorが発生している

Tags: python, tkinter

Python3.9.5 64bit　Windows10 Home

現在、Tkinterを使ってPDFを読み込み、いろいろな編集（回転、分割、保存など）を行うツールを作っています。
その途中段階として、次ページ/前ページのボタンをクリックすることでPDFを表示しているページが移動するというコードを書きたいのですが、どうも読み込みがうまくいきません。
書いたコードが以下になります（コードが長いため、ファイル読み込みにかかわらない部分は一部省いています）。
流れとしては、『読み込みボタンをクリック→ファイル選択画面が表示→任意のPDFファイルを読み込み→pillow画像のリサイズ→画面に表示』となっています。
下記のコードにはないのですが、実際はページ遷移のコードもあり、画面に表示されたあと次/前ページをクリックすることで表示されているPDFもページ移動するという具合です。

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500

def create_widgets(root):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)
    operation_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    operation_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)

    read_button = tk.Button(operation_frame, text='読み込み', command=file_read)
    read_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

    next_button = tk.Button(operation_frame, text='次ページ', command=next_page, state=tk.DISABLED)
    next_button.grid(column=0, row=5)

    prev_button = tk.Button(operation_frame, text='前ページ', command=prev_page, state=tk.DISABLED)
    prev_button.grid(column=0, row=6)

def file_read():
    path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[('PDFファイル', '*.pdf'),],
        title='ファイル選択',
    )

    size = (canvas_width, canvas_height)
    num_page = read(path, size)

    show_page = 0
    canvas.create_image(
        0, 0,
        image=get_image(show_page),
        anchor=tk.NW
    )

    change_state()

def read(path, size):
    pdf_path = path

    pillow_images = convert_from_path(
        pdf_path,
        poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-22.04.0\Library\bin'
    )

    x_ratio = size[0] / pillow_images[0].width
    y_ratio = size[1] / pillow_images[0].height

    image_ratio = min(x_ratio, y_ratio)

    resize_size = (
        int(pillow_images[0].width * image_ratio),
        int(pillow_images[0].height * image_ratio)
    )

    images = []
    for pillow_image in pillow_images:
        resize_image = pillow_image.resize(resize_size)
        tkinter_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image, master=root)
        images.append(tkinter_image)

    return len(images)

def get_image(num):
    if num < 0 or num >= len(images):
        return None

    return images[num]

root = tk.Tk()
PDFEditor = create_widgets(root)
root.mainloop()
```

しかし、実行するとcanvas.create_imageの箇所でcanvasが定義されていないというエラーが発生しました。

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10820\3221926224.py", line 11, in file_read
    canvas.create_image(
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

おそらく関数の定義や呼び出しの際に、何かが起きているのかと思います。
というのも、関数を定義せずに直書きしていた書き始めの頃は読み込みがおこなわれていてPDF表示されていたからです。
任意のページに対する表示ができていたので、今回はそれらを関数として定義して、全ページに対応させようとしていたところでした。
そのため（どう言葉にすればいいのか難しいのですが）、create_widgetsからfile_readに移った時にcreate_widgetsで書いたcanvasが引き継がれていない?のかなと感じました。

どう解決すればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [【Python】PDF編集アプリを開発](https://daeudaeu.com/python_pdf_editor/) PDFでは無いですがこちらも。[TkinterでImage Viewerを制作](https://qiita.com/kotai2003/items/7f23dc604a6b4b3b5898)

Comment: 変数のスコープの問題でしょうか？tkinterには詳しくないのですが、一般的にはグローバル変数にするか関数の引数として渡すかになるかと思います。

Comment: 他にはこんな記事とか？ [PDFファイルを回転して保存、分割・結合が一発！PythonでPyPDF2 \[コピペサンプルコード付き\]](https://kodocode.net/python-begin-pdf/), [Python PySimpleGUIで作るPDFリーダー](https://qlitre-weblog.com/pysimplegui-pdf-reader/), [Python-Projects/Moonlight PDF Reader](https://github.com/pyGuru123/Python-Projects/tree/master/Moonlight%20PDF%20Reader), [naiveHobo/pdfviewer](https://github.com/naiveHobo/pdfviewer), [3ricsonn/pyditor](https://github.com/3ricsonn/pyditor)

Comment: 記事、大変参考になりました。いつもありがとうございます...。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas` は 関数 `create_widgets` の中で使われている変数です。関数 `file_read` で使うには、何か工夫が必要です。

引数で渡すことにするなら、例えば下のようになります。`command` に渡す関数を、[ラムダ式(`lambda`)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) でその場で作っています。このラムダ式は `create_widgets` の中に有るので、`canvas` を参照できます。

```py
def create_widgets(root):
    # canvas の定義など
    # 省略...
    read_button = tk.Button(
        operation_frame,
        text='読み込み',
        command=lambda: file_read(canvas)
    )

# 省略...

def file_read(canvas):
    # 省略...
```

他にも、関数 `file_read` 自体を関数 `create_widgets` の中で定義してしまうなどの方法が考えられます。

Comment: 無名関数を初めて知りました。参考になりましたありがとうございます。